# Eclipse toString() generator with nested indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring, spring-tool-suite

Eclipse has a handy template for automatically generating the `toString()` method for a class. You can access it by hitting `Alt`+`Shift`+`S` and clicking on "`Generate toString()...`"

From there you can you can choose which fields to include in your derived `toString()`, and set other options to determine how it should be generated.

I would like to use it to quickly generate `toString()` methods for a large amount of classes.

Take this example, here is a `Song` class:

```
public class Song {
    private String title;
    private int lengthInSeconds;
    public Song(String title, int lengthInSeconds) {
        this.title = title;
        this.lengthInSeconds = lengthInSeconds;
    }
    // getters and setters...

}
```

And here is an `Album` class which holds an array of `Song`s:

```
public class Album {
    private Song[] songs;
    private int songCount;
    public Album(Song[] songs) {
        this.songs = songs;
        this.songCount = songs.length;
    }
    //getters...

}
```

I currently use this template to generate my `toString()` methods (with the "StringBuilder/StringBuffer - chained calls" option):

```
class ${object.className} {
    ${member.name}: ${member.value},
    ${otherMembers}
}
```

Which I can now use to generate the `toString()` for `Song`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("class Song {\n    ");
    if (title != null)
        builder.append("title: ").append(title).append(",\n    ");
    builder.append("lengthInSeconds: ").append(lengthInSeconds).append("\n}");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

and for `Album`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("class Album {\n    ");
    if (songs != null)
        builder.append("songs: ").append(Arrays.toString(songs)).append(",\n    ");
    builder.append("songCount: ").append(songCount).append("\n}");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Now, let's say I create an album and want to test its `toString()` like this:

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    Song[] songs = new Song[] { 
            new Song("We Will Rock You", 200), 
            new Song("Beat it", 150),
            new Song("Piano Man", 400) };
    Album album = new Album(songs);
    System.out.println(album);
}
```

This is what I get:

```
class Album {
    songs: [class Song {
    title: We Will Rock You,
    lengthInSeconds: 200
}, class Song {
    title: Beat it,
    lengthInSeconds: 150
}, class Song {
    title: Piano Man,
    lengthInSeconds: 400
}],
    songCount: 3
}
```

But what I would like is a generator that can nest indentation, like this:

```
class Album {
    songs: [class Song {
        title: We Will Rock You,
        lengthInSeconds: 200
    }, class Song {
        title: Beat it,
        lengthInSeconds: 150
    }, class Song {
        title: Piano Man,
        lengthInSeconds: 400
    }],
    songCount: 3
}
```

and continue to do so in the event of more classes inside each object, if that makes sense.

I tried to make a method that could replace a newline character with 4 spaces and a newline character before calling its `toString()`:

```
private String indentString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
}
```

The idea being that it could turn `"\n    "` in the append into `"\n        "` and so on but I'm not sure if it's even possible to call a function inside the eclipse template.

Anyone have any clue on how to do this? I have checked the documentation but it's pretty sparse. Looked all over SO as well but I'm not seeing any similar questions.

For reference I am specifically using Spring Tool Suite version 4.0.1RELEASE.

Comment: Do the indention in `Album` in `toString()`: `Arrays.toString(songs).replace("\n", "\n    ")` (instead of `Arrays.toString(songs)`).

Comment: @howlger but how can I do that within the eclipse generator template? I actually have a solution now which I will post later tonight when I get a chance.  It required creating a custom toString() builder. I would have preferred doing it with the template alone but I'm not sure it's even possible at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't the way I was hoping to do it, but I do have a solution. I was able to accomplish what I wanted by creating a [custom toString() builder class](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-tostring-styles.htm)

Here is the class I created:

```
/*
 * Helper class to generate formatted toString() methods for pojos
 */
public class CustomToStringBuilder {
    private StringBuilder builder;
    private Object o;

    public CustomToStringBuilder(Object o) {
         builder = new StringBuilder();
         this.o = o;
    }

    public CustomToStringBuilder appendItem(String s, Object o) {
        builder.append("    ").append(s).append(": ").append(toIndentedString(o)).append("\n");
        return this;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return "class " + o.getClass().getSimpleName() + "{ \n" + builder.toString() + "}";
    }

    /**
     * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
     * (except the first line).
     */
    private static String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
    }
}
```

Then I can use `Alt` + `Shift` + `S` -> "Generate toString()..." and "**select Custom toString() builder**" and choose my `CustomToStringBuilder`. With this, Eclipse generates the following code for `Song` and `Album`:

```
//Song
@Override
public String toString() {
    CustomToStringBuilder builder = new CustomToStringBuilder(this);
    builder.appendItem("title", title).appendItem("lengthInSeconds", lengthInSeconds);
    return builder.getString();
}

//Album
@Override
public String toString() {
    CustomToStringBuilder builder = new CustomToStringBuilder(this);
    builder.appendItem("songs", songs).appendItem("songCount", songCount);
    return builder.getString();
}
```

Putting it all together and running my test again gives me my desired result:

```
class Album{ 
    songs: [class Song{ 
        title: We Will Rock You
        lengthInSeconds: 200
    }, class Song{ 
        title: Beat it
        lengthInSeconds: 150
    }, class Song{ 
        title: Piano Man
        lengthInSeconds: 400
    }]
    songCount: 3
}
```

However, I would still prefer a method that did not require adding a new class to the source code if possible so I'll leave the question open for a day or two to see if anyone can find a different way to do it more easily.

Comment: Great answer. This is very useful for my requirements where I do not have the flexibility of third-party serialization add-ons such as Jackson/GSON/etc.